# How to texture paint on a different layer?

Tags: texture-painting

I want to know if its possible to have layers in blender when texture painting an object. Like in photoshop for example.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly like that, but you could combine different textures by using nodes, mix them all with the Mix RGB to have things like multiply, screen, add, color Burn and so on and you will see your textures over the "texture slot"
[image]

Answer (score 0):

To add to Emir's answer, you can use images with transparent background and use the *Alpha* output as factor:

[image]